# How to make the Google map assessable for viewer both from China and rest of the world?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, localization

Since Google provides its API from different domain in China, i.e. maps.google.cn, how should I load the API?

```
<script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Currently I'm only using this line and it works.

Is it possible to load the API from `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js` first, and if it's not assessable(i.e. user from China) then using `maps.google.cn` instead?

And will this approach be beneficial compared to load API from `maps.google.cn` no matter what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following guide from Google about [Loading the API in China](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region)

> The Google Maps JavaScript API is served within China from
>   `http://maps.google.cn`. When serving content to China, replace
>   `https://maps.googleapis.com` with `http://maps.google.cn`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
> </script>
> ```
>
> If you are specifically targeting users in China, you should add the
>   region and language parameters as well. The API supports both `zh-CN`
>   and `zh-TW` as values for the language parameter.
>
> ```
> <script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?region=cn&language=zh-CN&key=YOUR_API_KEY">
> </script>
> ```

---

The best option for your case would be to detect user's country based on client's IP address and load corresponding API.

For that you can use http://freegeoip.net/

```
freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}
```